# Fancybox not working in IE: object doesn't support this method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I use fancybox as image holder, it works all fine in all browsers except all versions of IE. I have viewed all the similar questions, but they didn't help.
My Doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.I've included the latest jQuery before the fancybox plugin in the header and I have no error warnings in firebug.
One of the pages is in: [Here](http://film.dachaocai.com/1087033) and the image section is in the bottom.
Please help me. Thanks beforehand.

If you are not convenient to go to see the page, this is my header :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="zh-CN">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://img.dachaocai.com/sys/fav.ico"  type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://img.dachaocai.com/css/global.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://img.dachaocai.com/js/jq.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://img.dachaocai.com/js/global.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">isUser=false; </script>
    <meta name="keywords" content="电影,铁甲钢拳 Real Steel(2011),肖恩·列维,休·杰克曼 / Dako,剧照,海报,预告片" />
    <meta name="description" content="电影 铁甲钢拳 Real Steel(2011) 的预告片, 简介, 评分, 影评, 剧照, 海报与讨论 · 大巢菜·电影·文艺·more" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://img.dachaocai.com/css/bmfview.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/clientscript/ui/jui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://img.dachaocai.com/js/fb/fb2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://img.dachaocai.com/js/bmf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http:///img.dachaocai.com/js/fb/fb.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    $(function(){
      $(".fb").fancybox();
      ui();
      $("#pics .pagelink").click(function(){$("#imgs").html("<div class=\"loader\"><img src=\"http://img.dachaocai.com/sys/spinnerActive.gif\"/></div>");$this=$(this);$.ajax({url:"/j/getpics",data:{"t":"film","tid":tid,"p":$(this).html()},success:function(data){$("#imgs").html(data);$(".fb").fancybox();$("#pics .pagelink").attr("id","");$this.attr("id","curpage");ui();}})});
});
function ui(){
    $(".imgholder img").hover(function(){$(this).animate({"border-top-width":"3px","border-left-width":"3px","border-right-width":"3px","border-bottom-width":"10px"},200);},function(){$(this).css("border-width","0px");});
}
    /*]]>*/
    </script>
    <title>铁甲钢拳 Real Steel(2011) · 大巢菜</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25549966-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'baidu', 'word']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'soso', 'w']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'yodao', 'q']);
    _gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'sogou', 'query']);

    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of this :

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
```

Or this :

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
<![endif]-->
```

try removing it

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember having a similar issue a few months ago with this as well and the work around was to force IE into IE 8 compatibility mode.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

Comment: Well，that's not the reason as I thought at first, since it didn't work in IE6,which doesn't support this meta tag, either. And my test testified that.:) Thanks for your effort anyway.